# Duplicate partitions (and lvm pv) when using hardware RAID

Tags: linux, lvm, hardware-raid

OS: Debian stretch, motherboard: ASUS H87I-PLUS.

I am trying to setup bootable hardware RAID1. Through motherboard menu I've created array of two drives (sdd and sde). This array is recognized by linux as md126.

Then I partitioned it into md126p1 (primary 1G, to use as /boot), md126p2 (extended) and md126p5 (secondary, lvm pv, to use as /root). Then I created volume group n using single pv on md126p5.

Now for some reason system sees partition table on md126 twice: as partitions of md126 and as partitions of sdd, so I get duplicate pv error:

```
WARNING: PV pcmcX0-vMQ3-z7Wq-cGpZ-5YrZ-0g8o-07xp5H on /dev/sdd5
was already found on /dev/md126p5.
WARNING: PV pcmcX0-vMQ3-z7Wq-cGpZ-5YrZ-0g8o-07xp5H prefers device
/dev/md126p5 because device is used by LV.
```

and `lsblk /dev/sdd` shows this:

```
sdd                      8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sdd1                   8:49   0     1G  0 part  
├─sdd2                   8:50   0     1K  0 part  
├─sdd5                   8:53   0 930.5G  0 part  
└─md126                  9:126  0 931.5G  0 raid1 
  ├─md126p1            259:0    0     1G  0 md    
  ├─md126p2            259:1    0     1K  0 md    
  └─md126p5            259:2    0 930.5G  0 md    
    └─n-root           253:4    0  29.6G  0 lvm
```

Also because of this grub refuses to boot from this new array (current system boots from sda).

Is it normal that partitions appear twice and how to fix it?

Comment: Instead of making a RAID from whole disks and partitioning md126, partition each disk and RAID the partitions individually.

Comment: *bootable hardware RAID1* and *This array is recognized by linux as md126* doesn't sound like hardware RAID at all.  Hardware RAID should present a one drive to the OS that looks like one drive, and it shouldn't show up as an `md` device. A true hardware RAID controller would present an "normal" `sd` device. Does `mdadm` show it as a *software* RAID device?

Comment: @AndrewHenle suprised me too, but i thought linux interfaced with hw raid somehow. Which command tells me what raid it is?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I wanted hw raid, and raid setup (ctrl-i during boot after uefi), only allowed to choose whole hdds, not partitions.

Comment: Then you need to set up RAID in the RAID BIOS. This is software RAID that you have set up.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i just pressed ctrl-i during boot (before linux boot menu) and set up raid in a text menu. I didn't run single mdadm command to create /dev/md126, it appeared after i did the above.

Comment: OK, so it's a fakeraid. Probably best to just ignore its existence and set up the software RAID partitions yourself with mdadm.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it's a "fake RAID", and has several drawbacks. I've switched to software RAID so I won't be figuring this out.